# Brand new Magsafe 2 charger LED light leaking from cable, is it faulty?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

This a brand new adapter from Apple store, there's a green light leakage from the cable at the magsafe 2 head, is this normal or it's faulty?

It's from UAE apple store and a friend got me the adapter sealed to Egypt so I can't go to apple store right away and replace it unless the friend take it again to UAE.

Sorry for being paranoid, I had terrible stories with repair shops in Egypt which ruined and burnt my previous adapter.

P.S. why not buying from Egypt? No apple stores and it costs 3x its price.
I added the Other picture because someone told me on other forum it's scratched not brand new while it was only a residue from the plastic wrap! So it's the same but with flash and the leak is barely visible.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would call that cosmetic manufacturing error, not functional error.

Nothing to worry about, but if you want to change it you can do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and assurance. If it will work properly I have to accept it then because it's not easy to send it back to another country and getting it replaced and sending it again to Egypt, unfortunately this is our situation.

Comment: It will work, it is cosmetic not functional issue